# Android: Passing a variable to a non-activity class

Tags: java, android, parameter-passing, android-notifications

I am trying to pass a String from my MainActivity to a non-activity class (A Notification Service) So that I can customise the notification message. I have tried using Intent however it won't work because it is a non-activity based class. What is the best why to do this?

I am currently trying to use a global variable but its not working.

MainActivity.java

```
private String var;
private String a = "Pumpkin";

public String getVar(){
    return var;
}
public void setVar(String a){
    var = a;
}
```

NotificationService.java

```
  MainActivity b = ((MainActivity)getApplicationContext());
  String var = b.getVar();
```

This crashes the app when even I call the variable var in NotificationService.java

Comment: It crashes because the application context is not your activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.You can try by making static variable, and call with Class refenrence in any where.

```
 public static  String a = "Pumpkin";//Declare in MainActivity
 Use it: String var = MainActivity.a;
```

2. Pass in Intent as extras and then get extras in where intent recived.

```
  startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PropertyListviewActivity.class).putExtra("Key", "Value"));
```

Recive :

```
 if (intent != null)
        if (intent.getExtras() != null)
            if (intent.getExtras().getString("Key") != null) {
                String recivedString= intent.getExtras().getString("Key");
```

3.Keep in Shared Preferences and retrive where ever you want(not good practise).

4.If Not an Android Component class try pass in Contractor.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using the second option. The first and the third are both essentially global variables and they make the application much harder to maintain. The Intent's extras are the closest thing to a method parameter. You don't need all those null checks if you're sure that you're passing the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try an event bus [Green Robot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [Otto Event Bus](http://square.github.io/otto/) both are excellent options.

Comment: I'd say that this is a rather advanced method. You should first learn to communicate via intents and messengers and the move to magical solutions like Otto.

Comment: You are right but i wrote out the easiest solution :) .

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast app Context to Activity. It crashes, cause app context is not an activity. You should use handleIntent or binder in your service to transport data.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Basics

Comment: Could you give an example on how to do that. Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend starting with messengers for IPC. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger

Answer (score -1):

you can do this task by saving data to application level variable or save it in sharedpreference.

To save data in application level
make a static variable like

```
public static DatatypeYouDesire(String/int) cachedData;
```

now when you want to store data jst initialize this varaible with the data you want to store
like

```
YourApplictionClass.cachedData = "your data to be stored";
```

similarly you can use this data by accesing YourApplicationClass.cacheData

Comment: While sometimes avoiding it requires extra work, global application state is bad.